# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)というエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: php, mysql

PHP、MySQL初心者のものです。

先ほど下記リンクのドットインストールの授業を見て、PHPからデータベースに接続をしようとしたところ、エラーが出てしまいました。

http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_php_db/34204

エラー文は
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
となっています。

ちなみにコードは

```
 <?php
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'dotinstall_db');
  define('DB_USERNAME', 'dbuser');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '適当な英数字');
  define('PDO_DSN', 'mysql:dbhost=localhost;dbname=' . DB_DATABASE);

try {
  // connect
  $db = new PDO(PDO_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  // insert
  $db->exec("insert into users (name, score) values ('taguchi', 55)");
  echo "user added!";

  // disconnect
  $db = null;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}
?>
```

というコードを書きました。
dbuserのアクセスが拒否されたとなっているので、そこが問題なのでしょうが、よくわかりません…。

dbuserでなくphpMyAdminのusernameか何かを調べてここに代入しないといけないということでしょうか？
詳しいかた、教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 一般的にはユーザー名・パスワードが間違っている時に出るエラーです。[そのシリーズの第2回](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_php_db/34202)でMySQLにユーザーを登録しているはずですが、その際に登録したユーザー名・パスワードを `DB_USERNAME` `DB_PASSWORD` に設定します。それぞれ「dbuser」「適当な英数字」であっていますか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。VagrantではなくXAMPPで仮想サーバーを立ち上げてやっているので、ユーザー名、パスワードを設定するところがよくわからず、とりあえずPHPMyAdminでデータベースを作ってコードを実行しようとしてしまっておりました。

XAMPPでやる場合には、どのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？